# How can I customize the ENOENT error inside an express webserver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, backend

I'm making a text hosting service and I want it to say "TextMessage Not found! You can create one in the name by clicking here" but I don't know how to do that.
I tried making a custom 404 error, and detecting if the file exists via the node fs module, that did not work out.

this is my code:

```
// Importing require packages/modules  
const express = require("express");  
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");  
const fs = require("fs");  
// Defining needed variables  
const app = express();  
const PORT = 3000;  
// Express midleware to enable body-parser  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));  
// Express static handler  
app.use(express.static("public"));  
// POST API To create message/file  
app.post("/api/message/submit", (req, res) => {  
  const file = req.body.messageText;  
  const fileID = req.body.messageID;  
  fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/messageFiles/" + fileID + ".txt",  
 file, (err) => {  
    if (err) res.send("ERROR! <br>" + err);  
    else res.send("Saved");  
  });  
});  
// GET API To read message/file        
app.get("/message/:id", (req, res) => {     
  const msg = req.params.id;    
  if (fs.existsSync(__dirname + "/messageFile/" + msg + ".txt")) {   
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/messageFiles/" + msg + ".txt");   
  } else {    
    res.send("Message does not exist");    
  }   
});   
// Running the server  
app.listen(PORT, () => {  
  console.log("Running on port: " + PORT);  
});
```

`

Comment: Please describe your issue more clearly and with examples of functions you wrote.

Comment: @jkalandarov I'm making a service for storing text files, and when a file is not found it returns express's default `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/runner/ExpressFormHandler/messageFiles/128.txt'` error, And I want to customize that error message, But I dont  know how.

Comment: Nobody can't help you unless you share your piece of code so that we can debug the problem. Otherwise, there are thousands of reasons that may cause that problem.

Comment: @jkalandarov I tried ` if (fs.existsSync(__dirname + "/messageFile/" + msg + ".txt")) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/messageFiles/" + msg + ".txt");
  } else {
    res.send("Message does not exist");
  }` but that always returned "Message does not exist" no matter what (Even if it did exist, It would return the error)

Comment: You can either share you code directly in your question by editing it, or you can share the screenshot of your code (still you will need to edit your question to paste the screenshot there).

Comment: "msg" is the "messageID" parameter given in the url, just incase you need that information

Comment: alright, Ill do that.

Comment: Done, I added the code you asked for @jkalandarov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try async writing to a file by wrapping it with `trycatch` block. It seems you have a problem with path to the file.

I suggest you to have a helper functions to write to a file and read from a file:

```
const create = async (data, fileName) => {
    try {
        const text = await fs.writeFile(`./files/${fileName}.txt`, data);
        console.log('File write successful!');
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('File write operation failed');
    }
};

const read = async (fileName) => {
    try {
        const fileContent = await fs.readFile(`./files/${fileName}.txt`, {encoding: 'utf-8'});
        return fileContent;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('File read operation failed');
    }
};

app.post("/api/message/submit", async (req, res) => {  
  const fileContent = req.body.messageText;  
  const fileID = req.body.messageID;  
  const message = await create(fileContent, fileID);
  message ? res.send('Successful') : res.send('Failed');
});

app.get("/message/:id", async (req, res) => {     
  const msgID = req.params.id;    
  const message = await read(msgID);
  res.send(message);
});
```

I hope it helps!

P.S.: Don't use too many comments. Your code should be self-documenting (readable)!

P.S.S: Added `async` keyword before `(req, res)`.

Comment: You may pre-create `files` folder in project root to avoid unexpected issues.

Comment: Unexpected reserved word: Await

Comment: Updated `app.post` and `app.get`. Added `async` keyword before `(req, res)`

Comment: By the way, `create()` and `read()` functions must be declared before app.get and app.post methods.

Comment: No, The issue isn't resolved. It returns an error saying "File read operation failed". I tried to fix it but I can't seem to find the cause of the error.

Comment: throw new Error(error.message) inside catch block to see the error message. and before that you can log the previous message "File read operation failed".

Comment: Fixed a bug in `read()` function. it should work now. Please try!

Comment: how do I close a question

Comment: Questions are closed by moderators only. Otherwise, they are left for better solutions. If you answer your own question, it will be closed and stay a wiki.